# Почему значения словаря выводятся не по порядку?

Tags: python, словари, python-2.7

```
Reg = {5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 4}
print Reg.values()
```

Вывод:

```
[4, 1, 3, 2]
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что значения должны идти по порядку?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что значения должны идти по порядку?

Comment: Вы не правильно понимаете. Словарь непредсказуем, поэтому придумали [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

Словари в Питоне неупорядоченны (до Питона 3.7). В зависимости от конкретной реализации/версии языка, порядка определения значений, переменных окружений ([`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)) порядок вывода может меняться даже для одинаковых словарей от запуска к запуску.

Текущая реализация в Python 3.6 и Pypy (Питон реализованный на RPython) предоставляет упорядоченные словари, но на это не следует рассчитывать—эта деталь реализации не гарантирована спецификацией языка: другие/прошлые/будущие реализации Питона могут использовать неупорядоченные словари.

Используйте [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), чтобы сохранить порядок вставки:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(zip("abc", range(5)))
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])
>>> _.values()
[0, 1, 2]
```

На Питоне 3.6 порядок именованных параметров сохраняется:

```
>>> OrderedDict(a=0, b=1, c=2)
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])
```

Но подобный синтаксис не обязан сохранять порядок на Питоне 2.7

Связанный вопрос: [Items in JSON object are out of order using "json.dumps"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10844064/4279)

Comment: насколько я заметил, словари в Python 2.7 _упорядочены по хэшам_, в частности для строковых ключей наблюдается упорядочение по алфавиту, но это просто побочный эффект реализации -- при изменении функции хеширования все может меняться как хочет.

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov порядок может зависеть от истории словаря (как добавлялись, удалялись элементы) и других деталей реализации, которые могут поменяться даже в bugfix выпуске. К тому же  CPython не является единственной реализацией Питона. Возможны реализации интерфейса словаря, в которых порядок с hash никак не связаны. Документация не обещает никакого порядка — не следует ни на какой порядок рассчитывать.

Answer (score 3):

Обычный словарь не гарантирует порядок элементов.

Воспользуйтесь [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
In [22]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [23]: Reg
Out[23]: {5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 4}

In [24]: oReg = OrderedDict(sorted(Reg.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

In [25]: print(oReg)
OrderedDict([(5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 3), (8, 4)])

In [26]: print(oReg.values())
odict_values([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [27]: oReg[6]
Out[27]: 2
```